# Keep Text width and height but "hide" it

Tags: html, css

Someone knows how to hide a text on a background(with gradients) but keep its height and width?
visibility:hidden on my span-Tag seems not to work. it should keep an inline element by the way.

edit:

```
<div><span>whatever</span><img src="whatever.jpg"/></div>
```

Comment: Please clarify what you are doing, some example would help.

Comment: Do you mean the span has a background which should remain visible, and text that should be hidden?

Comment: the problem was i need to keep the width of the text but the text should be invisible. it is left of an image which is positioned by the text before. setting the color to same as background wasnt possible becouse the container div has a bg with gradients - and its also possible to select it. and visibility:hidden doesnt work on a inline element like span.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use inline-block.

http://caniuse.com/#search=inline-block

HTML:

```
<div>
    <span>Foo bar boo baz</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div
{
    background: red;
}

div span
{
    display: inline-block;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use another nested `<span>` tag inside your tag.  The inside tag is the one that would be hidden while the outside keeps positionning.

EX:

```
<span id="outer">
  <span id="inner">
    <!-- whatever you want -->
  </span>
</span>
```

And then you style could look someting like this :

```
#outer {
  width: xxx;
  height: xxx;
  /*any other attributes */
}
#inner {
  display: inline; /*this is what would change to hidden*/
}
```

Hope this helps!